# Regex for combination of alphnumeric letters which has at least 2 uppercase letter or 1 number?

Tags: regex

I need a regex for combination of numbers and uppercase letters and maybe lowercase letters and `/,-` characters, which contains at least 4 characters.

But of course it should contain at least 2 uppercase letter **or** one number.

I tried this:

```
barcode_regex = r"(?=(?:.+[A-Z]))(?=(?:.+[0-9]))([a-zA-Z0-9/-]{4,})"
```

For example match such cases as follows:

```
ametFXUT0
G197-6STK
adipiscXWWFHH
A654/9023847
HYJ/54GFJ
hgdy67h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single lookahead to assert at least 4 characters, and the match either a single digit or 2 uppercase chars in the allowed ranges.

```
^(?=.{4})(?:[A-Za-z/,-]*\d|(?:[a-z\d/,-]*[A-Z]){2})[A-Za-z\d/,-]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{4})` Assert 4 charcters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z/,-]*\d`  Match optional allowed characters without a digit, then match a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[a-z\d/,-]*[A-Z]){2}` Match 2 times optional allowed characters withtout an uppercase char, then match an uppercase char
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[A-Za-z\d/,-]*` Match optional allowed characters
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Io7Ht8/1).

Comment: thank you very much. it worked by adding an & in your proposed regex...  barcode_regex =  (?=.{4,})(?!\d+\b)(?:[A-Za-z/,-]*\d|(?:[a-z\d/,-]*&[A-Z]){2})[A-Za-z\d/,-]*

Answer (score 1):

You could use two lookaheads combined via an alternation to check for 2 uppercase or 1 number:

```regex
^(?:(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d))[A-Za-z0-9/-]+$
```

### Demo

This regex patterns says to:

```regex
^
(?:
    (?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])  assert that 2 or more uppercase are present
    |                   OR
    (?=.*\d)            assert that at least one digit is present
)
[A-Za-z0-9/-]+          match any alphanumeric content (plus forward slash or dash)
$
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but when i use it in my code, it matches the words even if their letters are all lowercase without any number and uppercase letter...